# How does one do Ext.Require when the init function creates a viewport?

Tags: extjs, loader

I'm trying to 'require' some code for the loader, but my current onready function is giving me grief with the require ( it complains about the viewport not being created yet ). Since I assign content to the viewport on creation, I cant really require the content that I populate ( unless I create the viewport and then assign stuff to it, but meh ).

How the heck do I Ext.require[] with a function like this? ( or how can I restructure this function so it performs in the same way, whilst letting me run Ext.Require on an array?)

```
Host=function(){
return{
    centerPanelId: 'mainLayoutCenter',
    init: function(){
        //Enable the loader for dynamic loading of js, only dev pls
        Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
        Ext.QuickTips.init(); //ext needs this

        Ext.Loader.setPath("bleh","js/bleh"); //Project paths for the loaders

        if(!window.User){
            this.initialContent = Ext.create('bleh.Login');
        }

        //Our default View
        //this.initialContent = Ext.create('bleh.panel.Register');

        this.currentContent=this.initialContent;
        //Instantiate a viewport 
        this.viewport = Ext.create("bleh.viewport",{
            initialContent : this.initialContent
            ,host:this
        });

        //init function, to hande events for HTML elements etc
        //bleh.init();

    }

    ,setContent: function( contentPanel ){

       var center = Ext.getCmp(this.centerPanelId);

       if ( this.currentContent ) { center.remove(this.currentContent); }

       this.currentContent = contentPanel;
       center.add(this.currentContent);    
       center.doLayout(); 
       this.currentContent.show();
    }       

}               
}();            
Ext.onReady( Host.init, Host );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just require whatever you need before this block of code. It's already wrapped in an `onReady` block, so it will not be executed until all dependencies are available by default, as long as you require them.  Just add this above your code:

```
Ext.require([
    'bleh.login',
    'bleh.viewport'
]);
```